# Login to multiple magento admin panel

Tags: admin, adminhtml

I have one installation of Magento working in it's own DocumentRoot.
I have another installation of Magento working in it's own DocumentRoot

Both webroot are on the same server; so they both have the same IP, yet they have different domain names.

I can visit each frontend successfully, but I cannot login to both admin panels at the same time.  I'm constantly reading about it being a cookie issue, but even after clearing my cache, cookies, sessions... I still cannot login to them both simultaneously.

Why is this happening?  The two installations are completely independent of one another, they both use a different database.  I simply cannot understand this and it's very frustrating.

When I say that I cannot login, I mean that the login page does not log me in.  I receive no error or anything;  I'm just redirected to the login page again.

### UPDATE

As a user brilliantly pointed out, and I forgot to mention it, but I do have an SSL cert for the domain assigned to the IP.

### Somehow

I'm not sure how it worked, but I cleared all my cookies and cache, closed the browser and waited for everything to be released from the memory; like how you wait for a router to discharge after unplugging it and before replugging it.  I opened the browser (Chrome) in normal (not incognito mode) mode, opened both admin login panels in separate tabs, and it worked?

Given this new odd discovery that I haven't tried to replicate yet, I know that it is indeed possible to be logged into both panels; even when using the same IP.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just get a separate IP for the other domain, sounds like they then share the same SSL cert. As the SSL will requires its own ip.

Perhaps another alternative is to put the admin login onto a port number??

Comment: I had the feeling that it was an IP problem, but changing IPs is a big change just for a simple browser glitch.

Comment: read my update.

Answer (score -2):

Try logging in either in different browsers or one in normal mode and the other in incognito mode.